# Getting a 500 error in the redirect Url https://[mydomain.com]/signin-oidc from Azure AD in ASP.Net Core app

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm getting a 500 error as a result of the /signin-oidc redirect Url to our ASP.Net Core app host ( https://[mydomain.com]/signin-oidc ) from Azure AD.
I'm perplexed that this error started to come up only recently. 
This ASP.net Core app using Azure AD Identity for Authenticatication has been running without this 500 error for a couple months.
We haven't made any change to either our ASP.Net Core app or the settings in Azure AD for our app services.

Would appreciate any tip or suggestion on trouble-shooting and resolving this error.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I think you need to contact the Azure support team for assistance.

You can raise a support ticket on azure portal by following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).